# Add class active jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, class, click

I write a simple code for my menu, but I'm stuck with a jQuery problem and I can't find the error.

I want to apply the class .active on the " li " that the user have selected,
so I wrote this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.port-menu-item').click(function () {
    $('.port-menu-item').removeClass('.active');
    $(this).toggleClass('.active');
  });
});
```

```css
.port-menu-item {    
  padding: 25px 5px;
  position: relative;    
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(158, 157, 157);
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="port-side-menu">
  <li class="port-menu-item">Nature</li>
  <li class="port-menu-item">Nightlife</li>
  <li class="port-menu-item">People</li>
  <li class="port-menu-item">Projects</li>
</ul>
```

In I inspect the page, I can see that the class `.active` is correctly set, but the " li " doesn't change it style.

On codepen (https://codepen.io/Alfaver/pen/zPpZXv ) i posted the complete code.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these

```
 $('.port-menu-item').removeClass('.active');
 $(this).toggleClass('.active');
```

to

```
 $('.port-menu-item').removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
```

Remove the dot from class name

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code you have added a dot inside of **removeClass,toggleClass** parameter which is not method of using this **jquery** function `

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.port-menu-item').click(function () {
      $('.port-menu-item').removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});`
```

Comment: Thank also to you ! :D